# Xamarin Visual studio 2015 - Addin to serialize data in file?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with visual studio 2015 with Xamarin.

Actually I'm looking for quick solution to save data in file as json, and load them in any time I want.

My actual solution is to create custom functions to save in files for each platform : Android, iOS... There is any addin that can help to do that quickly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: are you using xamarin.forms?

Comment: yes i'm using xamarin forms

Comment: I am guessing. you did that in Android already? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79/saving-objects-to-file

Comment: I'm not looking to add custom class/functions for each plateform, android ios... but like addin that integrate all my solution, so I can use it quickly

Comment: Looking for something like [this](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache)?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis it's the best one? lite?

Comment: @Zeta there really isn't such a thing as 'the best one' in software development. You just have to determine which suits your requirements best. This one works fine!